# List View View.MeasureSpec

Tags: android, listview, measure

There is any way to measure the height of list view rows that have dynamic heights?

Im having a problem with measurements. The measure method in android is always returning the same size for each row

Comment: I had the same problem, check this out, it may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620764/android-listview-measure-height