# Set size of ListView base on his non-fixed elements heigth

Tags: android, listview

I have a layout defined as the following.

```
<ScrollView
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/section1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:text="@string/anomaly_products_title"
                android:textColor="@color/title"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/section1_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        .... Some Other section

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I also defined the item of the list as follows.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="13dp"
    android:background="@drawable/semi_rounded">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to set the height of the `ListView` to the height of all his elements and make it non-scrollable. The scroll must only occur on the parent `ScrollView`. For that, I have found the function `setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620764/android-listview-measure-height?answertab=votes#tab-top).

The problem is that my checkbox label can be displayed on multiple lines and thus increase the size of the item slightly. With many checkboxes in this situation, the `ListView` becomes scrollable.

Is There any way to handle that case?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest adding headers and footers to your `ListView` instead of a `ScrollView` and `ListView` combination. This is simple and easier to implement. Here's a [nice tutorial](http://mobiledevhub.com/2017/12/24/android-listview-headers-and-footers/) on how you might add headers/footers in a `ListView`.

Handling the height of the `ListView` based on the items count and item size is difficult and hard to optimize the overall process. You can also consider using a `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`. It has the option to add headers and footers as well. [Here's an implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31154402/3145960).

For adding multiple lists (multiple sections in your case), you might consider looking into this sample [Github Project](https://github.com/masudias/dynamic-recyclerview) which might give you a lead on how you might achieve the behavior that you want using a `RecyclerView`.

Hence, remove the `ScrollView`. Put the contents which are above of your `ListView` in a separate layout file and do the same for the contents below your `ListView`. Then add them as a header and footer accordingly.

Comment: what if there is more content in the scrollview that is not part of a list footer or header?

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I am actually confused about the more contents. The `ListView` is somewhere in the middle of the whole layout as I could understand from the question. Hence, everything which is above the `ListView` can be set as a header and everything below it can be set as a footer, which I was suggesting.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for the clarification. You can still achieve that using a `RecyclerView` as well. I am sharing a sample [Github Project](https://github.com/masudias/dynamic-recyclerview) which I think is applicable here.