# Issue when trying to calculate height of listview that has multiline TextView inside list item

Tags: android, listview, textview

I'm using this method to calculate the height of listview, but it's not really exactly as I want. Because, my listview have a TextView could be multiline when the content is so long. It's right when TextView is oneline, but when it has 2 lines, it's wrong height. Thank you!

**[Please see the error in this picture](http://postimg.org/image/gbgzohltr/)**

code

```
public static boolean setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter != null) {
            int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

            // Get total height of all items.
            int totalItemsHeight = 0;
            for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
                View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
                item.measure(0, 0);
                totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            // Get total height of all item dividers.
            int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() *
                    (numberOfItems - 1);

            // Set list height.
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight;
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
            listView.requestLayout();

            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/border_margin"
            android:text="name"
                android:paddingLeft="200dp"
            android:textColor="@color/header_lounge"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to show the textview in multi lines??

Comment: Check the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039913/android-how-to-measure-total-height-of-listview

Comment: Because I want to show all content of the TextView. So, I made it WRAP_CONTENT, but I met the problem when get the measure height of the row item include that TextView

Comment: Try to set android:maxLines="2" to TextView without run time calculate height.

Comment: I don't like to set maxLines because I want to show as much as content of TextView possible

Answer (score 5):

All the methods that are available to calculate height of `ListView` based on children fail when the `TextView` becomes **multiline**.

I too faced the same problem and after a lot of tries, I found the solution of this problem.

> The main concept is if you set the **exact number of lines** your `TextView` is having then the height will be calculated correctly i.e. you any how need to do the following,

```
textView.setLines(numberOfLines)
```

With this your problem will be solved.

Now the next question is how you can come to know the exact number of lines your TextView will be having dynamically.

I will say it totally depends on your scenario. In my case what I did was,

```
textView.setText(fullString);

WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
int screenWidth = display.getWidth(); // Get full screen width
int eightyPercent = (screenWidth * 80) / 100; // Calculate 80% of it
// as my adapter was having almost 80% of the whole screen width

float textWidth = textView.getPaint().measureText(fullString);
// this method will give you the total width required to display total String

int numberOfLines = ((int) textWidth/eightyPercent) + 1;
// calculate number of lines it might take

textView.setLines(numberOfLines);
```

Comment: Awesome  Solution its worked like gun shot.Thank you so much