# Android: ListView with expandable item that's not shown completely

Tags: android, android-listview

My problems is simply that i have a `ListView` and the items within that list are expandable.

There is a view that has visibility GONE, when i change visibility of the hidden item, and it's at the bottom of the screen, i need the list to `scroll` to show the hidden item.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried using an ExpandableListView?

Comment: What i need is a normal list, each item has 2 sections, a shown part and another part that can be hidden and shown.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to scroll to a specific item then?  ListView has a several methods that can help with that:

1) ListView.smoothScrollToPosition(int position)
2) ListView.setSelection(int position)

Take a look at these.

Comment: That's not it .. i'm already scrolled to that item .. but after showing the hidden section a part of the cell is lower than the bottom of the screen

Comment: I see. This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312683/calculate-the-size-of-a-list-view-or-how-to-tell-it-to-fully-expand